# How to report someone to HR when no longer work for company

Tags: management, human-resources, law

Recently I worked at a job and believe I should report my former manager to human resources. His attitude and demeanor was very rude/hostile/aggressive/abrasive, both when speaking about work and non-work related topics.

Any one of the things he did wouldn't be enough for me to inform HR, but the fact that he acted like this several times a day each day is what has me concerned. He would call me unprofessional, immature or a liar, and I did not understand where this was coming from. For example when I said I was reading up on a technology that I hadn't used before he said I had lied on my application form, but I never did say I knew it. A non-work related example was he asked if I had been to a parade over the weekend and I said no and he said I must not have any friends.

This did impact my ability to do work because when I needed to ask a question he would brush me off and act rude.

Many times I tried to resolve these issues and asked him to speak to me differently. After this didn't work I brought in his manager, yet it still didn't help. In fact, he forbid me to speak to anyone else unless it was about something personal (i.e. not work related). Other people in the building had problems with him too, but none had to work with him like I did.

Not sure if I should mention it, but he tried to coerce me to come back and work for free a couple days.

Something similar happened to me once before and I regretted not reporting the person to HR and have decided it would be the right thing to do for this. My question is, how do I report it to HR and what should I have ready? I wrote down the contact info of a few HR reps. Should I first phone or email?

A lot of what the way he acted isn't captured in his words. I can't quote his tone of voice and body language, which were very aggressive. How can I convey this?

I don't know why he acted this way and I don't think he realized he was doing it. I'm not sure if it's a cultural, or a mental illness or just how he thinks a manager is supposed to act. To be clear, I don't hold vice against him, though I don't think he needs more training if he's going to continue to be a manager and other people shouldn't have to deal with this.

UPDATE: while I appreciate the answers given, this is not up to debate. I'm not looking for why people think doing nothing is better, I'm looking for answers how the best way to proceed with contacting HR is.

Comment: Maybe you should write an anonymous review of the company on Glassdoor? Not likely to burn any bridges with this....

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I do this because I believe it's the right thing to do, not out of revenge. For example I learned that the manager had coerced the previous employee into working a bit for free, after his contracted ended, and he tried to get the same from me. I don't think it's right that he keeps doing this.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the purpose of HR. HR's purpose is to **protect the company from litigation from its (current and former) employees** and adhere to the law (with respect to record-keeping, labor regulations, etc). Unless you've spoken to a lawyer (IANAL) and the lawyer is in contact with HR, then HR will have little, if anything, to do with you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What do you hope to achieve? You no longer work there so why make the effort as he does not affect you anymore.

Perhaps it was just a clash of personalities and he gets on fine with the others.

It seems to me that you are being petty at best. Also consider that you may wish to get a reference from your old employer in the future. In addition somebody from the old company may end up working alongside you in the future.

I would just put all your efforts into your new job.

Comment: It definitely wasn't a clash of personalities as others complained about him too

Answer (score 20):

Since you have left rather than taking it to HR at the time, any complaint will almost certainly be dismissed as "sour grapes" unless ***extremely*** well documented, which by your own statement isn't the case.

You chose to get out of it rather than fighting it. You've made your decision.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to contact depends on your goals and what you are trying to achieve. If you want some sort of proof that you have reported this, than it should be done in writing with you keeping a copy of the report and some sort of receipt that it was received or sent.

If you want to HR to actually do something, your best bet would be to find an HR person that you know and trust and then have a face to face meeting.

In either case, it's a long shot: unless the HR department is totally incompetent or out of the loop, they already know about behavioral issues. The HR department first and foremost duty is to protect the company and guard the interests of the employer. While they often portrait themselves to be the advocate of the employees, they are not. They would only interfere if the behavioral issue is a problem for the company: potential legal action, high attrition rate, negative impact on productivity etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you intend to communicate to the HR department you have two choices - either phone them or email them. If you email them, they will have a written record that you may regret in the future. Either way they will probably ignore it as you do not work for them any more.

I suppose by communicating with them you get it off your chest. Perhaps better to either shout and scream at the wall or write the email but do not press the send button.